# Longest palindrome within a string

Tags: ruby

I am supposed to return the size of the largest palindrome within a given string. For example, if I pass `"racecar"`, I should get a return of `7`.  If I pass `"racecarveryfast"` or `"veryfastracecar"`, it should still return `7`. Specs I have to pass are:

```
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("a"), 1)
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("aa"), 2)
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("baa"), 2)
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("aab"), 2)
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("baabcd"), 4)
Test.assert_equals(longest_palindrome("baablkj12345432133d"), 9)
```

and I am passing the first four with this code:

```
def longest_palindrome s
  sub_count = 0

  palidrome_count = []
  s_array = s.chars

  puts "string: " + s
  puts "string array: " + s_array.to_s

  if s.reverse == s
    return s.size
  else
    s.match('(.)\1')[0].size
  end
end
```

My thought process from here is breaking apart the string into smaller chunks, maybe through a loop. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  i = 0
  a = []
  while !string[i..-1].empty?
     j = -1
   while !string[i..j].empty?
     s = string[i..j]
     if s.reverse == s
       a << s.length
     end
    j -= 1
   end
   i += 1
 end
  a.max
end
```

Comment: That's a much better algorithm. Could clear it up a little by having `!string[...].empty?` instead of `length >= 1`.

Comment: As a minor optimization I would consider keeping track of the current longest length and returning it at the end rather than pushing everything to an array and calling `#max`.

Comment: @tadman I was using this `!string[..].empty?` style in the beginning but something went wrong while coming up with the algorithm and hence changed it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  However, as a beginner, I am going to need to study the logic behind what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the string has `n` characters. First see if the entire string is a palindrome. If it is, return the string. Fini! If not, see if either of the two substrings of length `n-1` is a palindrome. If one is, return it. If not, examine substrings of length `n-2`, and so on. As long as the string contains at least one letter, the longest palindrome will be found.

```
def longest_palindrome(str)
  arr = str.downcase.chars
  str.length.downto(1) do |n|
    ana = arr.each_cons(n).find { |b| b == b.reverse }
    return ana.join if ana
  end
end
```

The key method here is [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Here are some examples<sup>1</sup>:

```
longest_palindrome "a"                     #=> "a" 
longest_palindrome "aa"                    #=> "aa" 
longest_palindrome "baa"                   #=> "aa" 
longest_palindrome "aab"                   #=> "aa" 
longest_palindrome "baabcd"                #=> "baab" 
longest_palindrome "baablkj12345432133d"   #=> "123454321" 
longest_palindrome "I heard tattarrattats" #=> "tattarrattat"
```

<sup>1 James Joyce coined the word "tattarrattat" in *Ulysses*, to mean a knock on the door.</sup>